# Can Client Credentials be used to create a Service Principal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an Azure AD Application that has been granted `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` permissions.  Using the Client Credentials flow, I can authenticate with that application and use the token to create another application.  (Lets call the newly created application "AppTwo")

I need "AppTwo" to have specific settings that are only available under the Service Principal of an application.  So, after I use the MS Graph API to create the application, I call a `POST` on `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals`, using the client credentials token that I used to create the application.

When I run this I get the following error:

> When using this permission, the backing application of the service principal being created must in the local tenant

But the [help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) for this operation says that `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` is sufficient permissions.  But it also seems to indicate that I need the *Application Developer* role.

But this page says that I don't: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference

It says that `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` can:

> Allows the calling app to create other applications and service principals, and fully manage those applications and service principals (read, update, update application secrets and delete), **without a signed-in user**. It cannot update any applications that it is not an owner of.

Do I really need that role to make a service principal?  Or am I getting some other error?

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was due to me passing in the `ObjectId` of the application.

Though most MS Graph APIs take the `ObjectId`, this one needs the `ClientId` (also know as the `ApplicationId` or `appId`).